# ReactiveMongo failing to descend in sort

Tags: mongodb

Using ReactiveMongo `0.11` for Scala `2.11`. I have an issue where my queries are failing to descend. The following is my Index and ReactiveMongo query:

```
collection.indexesManager.ensure(Index(Seq("userId" -> IndexType.Ascending, "lastActivity" -> IndexType.Descending), background = true))

def listEfforts(userId: String, page: Int, pageSize: Int): Future[\/[ErrMsg, List[EffortDesc]]] = {
      val query = BSONDocument("userId" -> userId)
      val sort = BSONDocument("lastActivity" -> -1)
      val skipN = (page - 1) * pageSize
      val queryOptions = new QueryOpts(skipN = skipN, batchSizeN = pageSize, flagsN = 0)

      collection.find(query).options(queryOptions).sort(sort).cursor[EffortDesc](ReadPreference.primaryPreferred).collect[List](pageSize).flatMap {
        case list => Future(\/.right(list))
      }
  }
```

What's happening is my results are all ascending, even though my sort variable has been set to `-1`. `lastActivity` is a Unix timestamp field in milliseconds. I've tried other debugging issues (like recompiling, etc.)

Any idea what could be causing this? Thanks for your help!

Comment: Have you tried the query in the MongoDB shell?

Comment: @cchantep negative that's a good idea I'll try that now. I can at least figure out if it's something weird in ReactiveMongo itself.

Comment: @cchantep okay found the issue...and it's weird. If I put a `IndexType.Descending` on `lastActivity` field and then additionally sort as descending, it will actually return ascending values. Wasn't expecting background indexes to actually be affected by sorts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the issue. If I put a IndexType.Descending on lastActivity field and then additionally sort as "descending" (via `"lastActivity" -> -1`) MongoDB will first return a descended sort according to its index and then sort it again.

I'm not sure if this is normal/expected behavior in Mongo but changing `-1` to `1` fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Using either

`("fieldName", BSONInteger.apply(1))`

or

`("fieldName", BSONInteger.apply(-1))`

works for me.